# finding lowest number between its 2 neighboor in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to exectute a function, preferably inside the forEach, for every element that is surrendered by 2 higher or equal number, or if its first or last element, just compared to second, or second last number.

I come up with this code, but I'm sure there is a better way:

```
var Pointdata = [98,59,39,0,48,85,19,43,3,98,65,100];

    Pointdata.forEach(function(Current,i,array){

  if (Current <= array[i+1] && Current <= array[i-1]) {
  DrawPoint(Current,i,array);
  }
  else if (Current <= array[i+1] && i == 0) {
  DrawPoint(Current,i,array);
  }
  else if(Current <= array[i-1] && i+1 == array.length) {
  DrawPoint(Current,i,array);
  }

function DrawPoint(Current,i,array) { 
// marks peak points of canavas chart.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just a single condition inside, `Current` is `a`.

```
if ((i + 1 === array.length || a <= array[i + 1]) && (i === 0 || a <= array[i - 1])) {
    DrawPoint(a, i, array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
for (i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
  var Current = array[i];

  if (Current <= array[i+1] && Current <= array[i-1]) {
   DrawPoint(Current,i,array);
  }
}
```

Couple of benefits:

1. You can skip edge cases like start and end indices
2. Only one conditional to think about

But if you want to keep those edge cases you can write them all in one if block separating them by or conditions like `if ((Current <= array[i+1] && Current <= array[i-1]) || (Current <= array[i+1] && i == 0) || (Current <= array[i-1] && i+1 == array.length))`

Answer (score 0):

```
function markPeaks(data, draw) {
  var xs = [Infinity].concat(data).concat(Infinity)
  xs.forEach(function(x, i, array) {
    if (Number.isFinite(x)) // skip first and last
      if (array[i-1] >= x && x <= array[i+1]) // n-1 ≥ n ≤ n+1
        draw(x, i-1, array) // minus1 because of 1st 'helper' Infinity
  })
}

markPeaks(/*pointdata, /*drawpoint*/)
```